# Issue With Overlapping Fixed Objects

Tags: css

Here's a fiddle:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ry59aomd/)

CSS:

```
.navbar img{
    background: #0066FF;
    width: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    -webkit -transition: width 0.5s;
}
.navbar img:hover{
    background: #99CCFF;
    width: 125px;
    clear: both;
}
#1{
    top: 0px;
}
#2{
    top: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#3{
    top: 100px;
}
#4{
    top: 150px;
}
body {
 margin: 0px;
 }
```

Essentially, I just want each individual square to not overlap each other.  I've been trying to use margins, but I must be doing something wrong. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't need to have the fixed position you can do it this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/ry59aomd/3/

your css code can be simplified to:

```
.navbar img{
    background: #0066FF;
    width: 50px;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    -webkit -transition: width 0.5s;
}

.navbar a{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}

.navbar img:hover{
    background: #99CCFF;
    width: 125px;
}
```

Your html code can be simplified too:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png"/></a>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png"/></a>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png"/></a>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png"/></a>
</div>
```

The fiddle above shows the output (and you could then position the whole navbar, rather than the individual elements)

```
.navbar {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```